# Init the CGPDFDocumentRef with Custom contents return from my PHP Server

Tags: php, iphone, pdf

I want to display the PDF in iPhone using the PDF Contents return by my PHP Server. How to do this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use UIWebView sample code is below....

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"your pdf path"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[obj_WebView loadRequest:request];
```

please check it. I think it's helpful to you.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your sharing but i am using CGPDFDocumentRef and Quartz later to parse the pdf document but this only helps for web view